# Web scraping headlines and subtitles from a specific section with a specific tag id

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping

Tried the following code to get the headlines and subtitles from the section https://www.theguardian.com/uk/environment with the id: environment/wildlife for the period of time October, November, December 2022.
Any ideas on what can be wrong? Thanks for your help.

`

```
r = requests.get('https://www.theguardian.com/uk/environment')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all('gu-island')
filtered_elements = [element for element in elements if element['props']['id'] == 'environment/wildlife']
headlines = []
for element in filtered_elements:
    headlines.extend(element.find_all('h1'))
texts = [headline.text for headline in headlines]
print(texts)
```

`

Also tried with the keyword wildlife but no results.

`

```
r = requests.get('https://www.theguardian.com/uk/environment')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all('gu-island')
filtered_elements = [element for element in elements if 'wildlife' in element['props']['tags']]
headlines = []
for element in filtered_elements:
    headlines.extend(element.find_all('h1'))
texts = [headline.text for headline in headlines]
print(texts)
```

`

The following code with the url of a specific article, does extract the headline subtitle but also the entire text of the article which I'm not requesting.

`

```
r = requests.get('https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2022/dec/30/tales-of-killer-wild-boar-in-uk-are-hogwash-say-environmentalists')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
headlines = soup.find_all('h1')
standfirst = soup.find_all('p')
for headline in headlines:
    print(headline.text)
for standfirst in standfirst:
    print(standfirst.text)
```

`

Comment: I can't find any elements in the html upon inspecting the page, named "gu-island" can you post your results. Also, your final example, you are scraping from an entirely new link, so is it the main page that you need or the new link that you need?

Answer (score 1):

Just inspect your page, I'm assuming you want the title for every article from the main page as you didn't specify it clearly.

[image]

With the information, you can search the section as follows,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.theguardian.com/uk/environment')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "fc-item__content"})
for item in items:
    print(item.text.strip())
```

Tip: use .strip() to get the inner text within the A tag.

Output gives you:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following script will extract all of the **headlines** from the environment/**wildlife** pages. 

An example **url** from the *3rd Oct 2022* would be:

```
https://www.theguardian.com/environment/wildlife/2022/oct/03/all
```

You can modify the script to specify the required `start_date` and `end_date`.
Please note, you will have to specify an end_date that is one day beyond the end date you want.

All of the headlines within those dates will be stored in the `headlines` variable.
I have also introduced a sleep time of 10 seconds between page reads, to avoid being blocked by the website.

#### Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

def get_headings(dt):
    p = dt.strftime("%Y-%b-%d").split('-')
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.theguardian.com/environment/wildlife/{p[0]}/{p[1].lower()}/{p[2]}/all')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    elements = soup.select('div.fc-slice-wrapper')
    headings = [h.text for h in elements[0].find_all(class_="js-headline-text")][::2]
    return headings

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)


start_date = date(2022,10,1)
end_date = date(2022,10,4)

headlines = []
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    headlines.extend(get_headings(single_date))
    sleep(10) # sleep 10 seconds between each page to avoid being blocked

for h in headlines:
    print(h)
```

#### Output:

```
Gardeners beware: household chemicals banned overseas are still used in Australia
Cop15 is an opportunity to save nature. We can’t afford another decade of failure
Prince Harry wildlife NGO under fire after elephants kill three in Malawi
Country diary: Mysterious birdsong fills the air with sweetness
Tory MPs dismiss critical RSPB campaign as ‘marketing strategy’
Australia announces plan to halt extinction crisis and save 110 species
Sixty endangered greater gliders found in Victorian forests tagged for logging
Wales unveils plans to triple rate of peatland restoration
Europe and UK hit by ‘unprecedented’ number of bird flu cases this summer
```